# как подключать отдельные файли .py в основной код

Tags: python, telethon

у меня есть два кода написаных на `python`.
Первый код это `main.py` , второй в папке `lib` под названиям `session.py`

вопрос: как мне в основной код импортировать файл `session.py`

main.py

```
connect = connect()
user = connect.client_connection(phone , api , hash)
```

session.py

```
class connect:
   def client_connection(phone , api_id , api_hash):
      client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id , api_hash)
      client.start()
      return client
```

Comment: `from session import connect` возможно?

Answer (score 0):

Ну как-как, вот так:

```
import session
```

(придётся указывать `session.connect...`)
или

```
from session import connect
```

(просто `connect...`)